# How to filter Django objects based on value returned by a method?

Tags: python, django

I have an Django object with a method `get_volume_sum(self)` that return a float, and I would like to query the top n objects with the highest value, how can I do that?

For example I could do a loop like this but I would like a more elegant solution.

```
vol = []
obj = []
for m in Market.object.filter(**args): #  3000 objects
    sum = m.get_volume_sum()
    vol.append(sum)
    obj.append(m.id)
top = search_top_n(obj, vol, n)
```

And this is how the method looks like:

```
# return sum of volume over last hours
def get_volume_sum(self, hours):
    return Candle.objects.filter(market=self,
                                 dt__gte=timezone.now()-timedelta(hours=hours)
                                 ).aggregate(models.Sum('vo'))
```

From what I see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-n-largest-elements-from-a-list/) even with Python there isn't a single line solution.

Comment: How does `get_volume_sum` looks like. You can not filter a `QuerySet` based on a method, since the database does not know about the methods. Normally it is better to do the logic at the database side, since that will be faster.

Comment: hi @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the answer, I added how the method looks like. thanks!

Comment: where does the `hours` comes in in the `m.get_volume_sum()`?

Comment: `hours` comes from another method on another object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not filter with the method, this will result in an *N+1* problem: for 3'000 `Market` objects, it will generate an additional 3'0000 queries to obtain the volumes.

You can do this in *bulk* with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

hours = 12  # some value for hours

Market.objects.filter(
    **args,
    candle__dt__gte=timezone.now()-timedelta(hours=hours),
).annotate(
    candle_vol=Sum('candle__vo')
).order_by('-candle_vol')
```

Here there is however a small caveat: if there is no related `Candle`, then these `Market`s will be filtered out. We can prevent that by allowing also `Market`s without `Candle`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

hours = 12  # some value for hours

Market.objects.filter(
    Q(candle__dt__gte=timezone.now()-timedelta(hours=hours)) |
    Q(candle=None),
    **args
).annotate(
    candle_vol=Sum('candle__vo')
).order_by('-candle_vol')
```